# Rotation and Position Tracking with OpenCV and Optical Flow

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

I would like to track the rotation and translation of an object in OpenCV using Optical Flow. So far I've got something like this:

1. Call goodFeaturesToTrack to find initial features
2. Call calcOpticalFlowPyrLK to track the movement of feature points
3. Call findHomography to find how the points in image A moved to image B
4. Call perspectiveTransform to move points based on the homography
5. Call solvePnPRansac to find the rotation matrix and translation
   vector

At this point I'm trying to take the difference between the rotation and translation Mat between images and add them to an initial Rotation and Translation Matrix.

```
cv::solvePnPRansac(pattern.points3d, _points2d, calibration.getIntrinsic(), calibration.getDistorsion(), raux, taux);
raux.convertTo(Rvec, CV_32F);
taux.convertTo(Tvec, CV_32F);

cv::Mat_<float> rotMat(3, 3);
cv::Rodrigues(Rvec, rotMat);
cv::Mat_<float> transDiff   = _prevTranslation - Tvec;
cv::Mat_<float> rotDiff     = _prevRotation    - rotMat;
_absRotation                += rotDiff;
_absTranslation             += transDiff;
```

The problem with this approach is translation vector doesn't follow the images. The vector tends to stay in the range
[0.02 0.2 -1.5]

It doesn't stray far from this position.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it same through out the video? If not, then it may be because there is not much difference between frames. Try reducing frame rate when recording or skipping few frames when processing.